# javascript datetime add zero to single digit values

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime, string-formatting

i have this way of getting tomorrows date.

```
var tomorrow = date.getDate() + "/" + month + "/" + date.getFullYear();
```

this returns **2/10/2013** where as i want it to be **02/10/2013** (with the zero for single digits)

This is needed to do a date comparison.

```
if(02/10/2013==2/10/2013){
dosomething();
}
```

The above doesnt work due to that issue.

Comment: If you concatinate a character to a number or a date value, the result will be changed into a string. Although your syntax is wrong, the comparison will ever fail.

Comment: @reporter can you be more specific? is it a possible thing to do or nor ?

Comment: I assume you want `0` added to months too.

Comment: @mazraara you have to change both date values into strings and you have to format each date value with the same way.

Comment: @Andy yes a good pick. i forgot that.

Comment: @mazraara: I think you are looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/qgkVJ/). Correct?

Comment: @mazraara If you are satisfied then accept any one answer

Comment: @SwapnilPatil done. tnx a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do by

```
var tomorrow = ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/" +  ('0' + (date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + "/" + date.getFullYear();
```

Comment: @Swaapnil it will always have the zero in front isnt it ?  02/10/2013 && 021/10/2013

Comment: @mazraara NO dude,In that case slice will work it gives us the last two characters "21" in case of "021".

Comment: will it add the leading zeros for months too ? i mean when month is less than 10 it should be added a zero in front

Comment: This is wrong what if date is already double digit for example 12? leading zero will make it 012

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI No, As we have `.slice(-2)` over it. It will remove the preceding zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', tomorrow);
```

You could also use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library for time/date manipulation

Comment: will this prevent when digit is a 2 digit ? i mean adding zero only if its a single digit ?

Comment: wlil this happen ? 021/10/2013

Comment: this will do exactly what you wanted it uses jquery datepicker widget

Comment: No it will not happen ( 021/10/2013 )

Comment: will it add the leading zeros for months too ? i mean when month is less than 10 it should be added a zero in front

Comment: doesnt work and gives this error.  b.getDate is not a function.. i guess this is because jquery UI is not loaded.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38413/discussion-between-alex-art-and-mazraara)

Answer (score 1):

why you don't use str_pad from phpjs.org this is the code :

```
  function str_pad (input, pad_length, pad_string, pad_type) {
  // http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net
  // +   original by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // + namespaced by: Michael White (http://getsprink.com)
  // +      input by: Marco van Oort
  // +   bugfixed by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  // *     example 1: str_pad('Kevin van Zonneveld', 30, '-=', 'STR_PAD_LEFT');
  // *     returns 1: '-=-=-=-=-=-Kevin van Zonneveld'
  // *     example 2: str_pad('Kevin van Zonneveld', 30, '-', 'STR_PAD_BOTH');
  // *     returns 2: '------Kevin van Zonneveld-----'
  var half = '',
    pad_to_go;

  var str_pad_repeater = function (s, len) {
    var collect = '',
      i;

    while (collect.length < len) {
      collect += s;
    }
    collect = collect.substr(0, len);

    return collect;
  };

  input += '';
  pad_string = pad_string !== undefined ? pad_string : ' ';

  if (pad_type !== 'STR_PAD_LEFT' && pad_type !== 'STR_PAD_RIGHT' && pad_type !== 'STR_PAD_BOTH') {
    pad_type = 'STR_PAD_RIGHT';
  }
  if ((pad_to_go = pad_length - input.length) > 0) {
    if (pad_type === 'STR_PAD_LEFT') {
      input = str_pad_repeater(pad_string, pad_to_go) + input;
    } else if (pad_type === 'STR_PAD_RIGHT') {
      input = input + str_pad_repeater(pad_string, pad_to_go);
    } else if (pad_type === 'STR_PAD_BOTH') {
      half = str_pad_repeater(pad_string, Math.ceil(pad_to_go / 2));
      input = half + input + half;
      input = input.substr(0, pad_length);
    }
  }

  return input;
}
```

and apply it to your code:

```
var tomorrow = str_pad(date.getDate(),2,0,'STR_PAD_LEFT') + "/" + str_pad(month,2,0,'STR_PAD_LEFT') + "/" + date.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(new Date(2013,2,10).toString() == new Date(2013,02,10).toString()){
    dosomething();
}
```